# Where should I implement "viewport"(HTML, CSS or both)?

Tags: html, css, viewport

I'd like to know what is more common or useful.

Is it the typical viewport meta tag in HTML or in CSS?

```
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: device-width;
}
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Is it even possible to use just both?
And please give me the code that is most useful for compatibility for mobile devices, also when using a mobile device across.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Every website I know uses the second one, i.e. the HTML meta tag. I wasn't even aware the first one (CSS @viewport) exists...

Comment: https://www.caniuse.com/#search=%40viewport

Comment: @SLaks Ah, that's why I wasn't aware of it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical place to set viewport metadata is in HTML.

The common practice for addressing mobile devices is just like the HTML you included above, ie:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

or also as

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

See this [CSS-Tricks post for more information on setting `viewport` metadata](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/).

Answer (score 0):

You should always have it on the html. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) for more info